# Using the same coding key in two structs when decoding JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm making a small app to practice parsing JSON into a tableview, and I'm using the Ticketmaster API. [This is the JSON](https://pastebin.com/PQfx20SG), and these are the structs that I have set up:

```
struct Welcome: Decodable {
    let embedded: WelcomeEmbedded
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case embedded = "_embedded"
    }
}

struct WelcomeEmbedded: Decodable {
    let events: [Event]
}

struct Event: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let dates: Dates
    let eventUrl: String?
    let embedded: EventEmbedded

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case dates
        case eventUrl
        case embedded = "_embedded"
    }
}

struct EventEmbedded: Decodable {
    let venue: Venue
}

struct Dates: Decodable {
    let start, end: End
}

struct Venue: Decodable {
    let name: String
}
```

Before adding in the value `let embedded: EventEmbedded` to the `Event` struct, things worked fine, but after adding in that line, when running the app I get an error:

`Error decoding JSON: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "events", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "venue", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

I'm wondering how adding that line alone results in an error, is it anything to do with the fact that I have a value named `embedded` in two structs (`Welcome` and `Event`), and both use the coding key `_embedded`?

For some added detail, to parse the JSON I have a variable `var eventData = [Event]()` and call this function in `viewDidLoad` to populate `eventData` with the necessary data:

```
    fetchData(url: apiUrl) { (result: FetchResult<Welcome>) -> (Void) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let object): self.eventData = object.embedded.events
        case .failure(let error): print("\nError decoding JSON: \(error)\n\n")
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

The error also says `CodingKeys(stringValue: "venue", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.`. But looking at the JSON, the data under `venue` is structured the same way as the rest of the values, and they don't give me an error.

What can I do differently here to get back on track?

Comment: The typeMismatch error is pretty clear: The value for key `venue` is an array (note the `[]` in the JSON): `let venue: [Venue]`

Comment: Oh man, I was really focusing on the wrong thing here. Sorry for the silly question! So I'm just going to change `Venue` to `[Venue]` then access the `name` value with a subscript then I think, correct?

Comment: Yes, `cell.venueLabel.text = event.embedded.venue[0].name` worked. You're amazing vadian thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I'm curious though, why is it necessary to use the subscript to access the values in `venue`, but not `events`? They're both arrays, aren't they?

Comment: `event` is obviously one item of the array.

Comment: @KingTim When debugging stuff like that,  I find it helpful to use Postman to hit the API before opening Xcode. It's a lot faster to figure out what kind of data's coming back by looking at a response in Postman than throwing in . Gbreakpoints and doing `po <whatever your response is>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please learn to read `Codable` errors. They are very, very, very descriptive.

> Error decoding JSON: **typeMismatch**(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [**CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded"**, intValue: nil), **CodingKeys(stringValue: "events"**, intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), **CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded"**, intValue: nil), **CodingKeys(stringValue: "venue"**, intValue: nil)], debugDescription: **"Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.**", underlyingError: nil))

- `typeMismatch` is the error type
- `CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded",  CodingKeys(stringValue: "events"), CodingKeys(stringValue: "_embedded"), CodingKeys(stringValue: "venue")` is the key path (`_embedded/events/_embedded/venue`)
- `Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead` is the error message.

  - `Expected` is the wrong type you proposed.
  - `found` is the actual type.

    A `dictionary` is the struct, an `array` is an array of the struct.

Change `EventEmbedded` to

```
struct EventEmbedded: Decodable {
    let venue: [Venue]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a little more clear now that you point it out - I saw the error mention `_embedded` a few times and thought that there were issues there, when in fact the error message was just following the "path" through the values to the actual error of `Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead`.